# Handling errors in Iframes while uploading files and posting to iframe in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: iframe, exception

I am using a hidden iframe to upload files from ASP.NET MVC application. The role of iframe here is just to keep control on the same page during the post because form is posted to the iframe.

I am using onload method on iframe to display confirmation msgs or error messages based on msges returned from the controller.

But when I encounter an exception in controller, I can trap it but I can't dicplay appropriate  mesaage to user as Onload event of iframe does not get triggered.

Is there any way to trap error messages in a iframe.